# how to make cmake's ZERO_CHECK detect deleted files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I'd like to make ZERO_CHECK rebuild when I add or remove a file (or add a new file in a subfolder).

Right now I have to rerun the cmake.exe manually which is not ideal... particularly when the project is shared with other developers.

Right now I see this line in the ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj

cmake.exe -HE:[project] -BE:[project out] --check-stamp-list CMakeFiles/generate.stamp.list --vs-solution-file "$(SolutionPath)"

Are there any cmake settings that allow me to change this behavior to be more aggressive with checks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically detect newly added source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618281/automatically-detect-newly-added-source-file)