# Automatically detect newly added source file

Tags: cmake

My problem is that I am forced to rerun CMake each time I add a new source file, which is really annoying... Is there any way CMake could detect newly added source file automatically?

Comment: No, there is no non-hacky way.

Comment: How do you expect cmake to detect new source files unless you rerun it?   Chicken, egg, and all that.

Comment: Do you use `file(GLOB ...)` to discover your files? Then you have to re-run CMake each time, so it will run that command again. Normally you would list all your source files in your `CMakeLists.txt` and if you add a file there CMake would automatically re-run to generate new build/make files.

Comment: You may write a simple script, that build a hash of source tree and re-run cmake if necessary. Example from WorldOfTanks engine: https://github.com/dava/dava.engine/blob/development/Sources/CMake/Scripts/file_tree_hash.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake does not have functionality to observe a folder. Some OS (e.g. MacOS X) can execute an action in case a folder was changed. Some IDEs (e.g. QtCreator V4.1 and newer) trigger an re-run of CMake in case any of the CMake files where changed.

I do not know your use case but I recommend not to use `file(GLOB ...)`. It is better to know which files are part of your project.

Answer (score 0):

CMake does not offer such a way. How should CMake detect these new files without being called?

I am not sure whether Xcode or Visual Studio automatically re-runs CMake when new files are added.

Comment: Xcode re-runs Cmake but often halfway through the build.. which is unpleasant.